# how do i use the latest google visualisation API in greasemonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey, google-api

trying to get google visualisation API to work in greasemonkey (firefox) i tried to just use:

```
  // @require          http://www.google.com/jsapi
```

but then i get an Error: google.visualization is undefined

after adding:

```
//  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
```

i get the Error: $ is not defined

am i requiring the wrong thing? please help.

thanks in advance for useful answers!

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar question concerning the Google Maps API.

in my case, i had to append the API to the page with

```
API_js_callback = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=BR&callback=initialize";

var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = API_js_callback;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    (head || document.body).appendChild(script);
```

and `google` had to be called as `unsafeWindow.google`, so i added `google = unsafeWindow.google` as well.

```
initialize = setTimeout(function () {
    google = unsafeWindow.google;
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    .
    .
    .
```

check the full code and explanation here: [how to use the google maps api with greasemonkey to read a table of addresses and trace the route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894996/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-with-greasemonkey-to-read-a-table-of-addresses-an)