# Google Map API v3 - and Geocoding (UK postcodes)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need a simple way to display a map, using the API v3, which is generated by using a UK postcode. No search field needed, just a static postcode per map.

Does anyone have a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and posted the code here:

[how to use the google maps api with greasemonkey to read a table of addresses and trace the route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894996/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-with-greasemonkey-to-read-a-table-of-addresses-an)

Take a look and check if it helps you.

The code below uses the USA zip code to return the state, but i believe you can modify it to your needs.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function getState(zipcode) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function (result, status) {
        var state = "N/A";
        for (var component in result[0]['address_components']) {
            for (var i in result[0]['address_components'][component]['types']) {
                if (result[0]['address_components'][component]['types'][i] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    state = result[0]['address_components'][component]['short_name'];
                    // do stuff with the state here!
                    document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = state;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

--- EDITED [28/10/2011] ---

ok. very simple example, no code needed.
[click here](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=SW1A,UK&zoom=16&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false).

all you have to do is change the postcode **SW1A** where it says `center=SW1A,UK`.
cant get any simpler than that :)

Comment: thanks for the response... but to be honest i'm still a bit lost.