# remove "bullet" symbol from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a script that reads a list of addresses from a table and trace the route on google maps.

(Similar to my old one: [how to use the google maps api with greasemonkey to read a table of addresses and trace the route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894996/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-with-greasemonkey-to-read-a-table-of-addresses-an))

But there is a "bullet" symbol in front of every address, and google maps wont remove it to render the map, giving me the error below

[image]

this is the HTML for the table cell

[image]

Any hints on how to remove the "bullet" with JQuery/Javascript?

Comment: the most efficient way is to change the code that reads the data. Can you give us a sample of that? Otherwise, using JS to fix it at a later stage can be problematic.

Comment: Have you tried replace method? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: If its always there, chop it off? `"• bleep bloop".substr(2)`

Comment: Im not sure that it will always be there. Isnt there an ASCII code or something similar?

Comment: Paste the actual source HTML with the "bullet" in it -- or better yet, link to the whole page.  There's more than one way to make a "bullet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to `.substr(2)` you can replace the 1st occurrence with:

```
var s = $("#para").text().replace("\u2022", "");
```

Where `\u2022` is the character for the html bullet entity `&bull;`

Comment: This could work but it's not a general approach as the replace works in allt he string (ok, I know it's very unlikely to have bullets INSIDE the string, but this problem should be addressed in a general manner).

Comment: It works for the 1st occurrence only, subsequent ones will be ignored & it wont arbitrarily chop off the 1st 2 characters if the char is not present. If you wanted to anchor it to the start you could use `/^\u2022\s/`

Comment: @Cranio Probably. And feel free to correct me if im wrong (im not very good with regex), but cant i just add `/g` to do a global replace?

Comment: No, because the "global" part still refers to a single string ("global" means "replace all the occurrences *in the string*"). In other words, regex has no awareness of an "object/element collection".

Comment: @Cranio by "global" i meant in the string (the `var s` int this example). like 1 bullet at the beginning, and another one at the end.

Comment: If so, then it's ok. But still it works only for the first occurrence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12709/discussion-between-rasg-and-cranio)

Comment: To replace them all; `var s = $("#para").text().replace(/\u25AA/g, "");`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".dadosf").each(   
 function(i,e)
 {
     $(e).text($(e).text().substring(2));
 }
);
```

​
JQuery's `.each()` iterates through the collection, we simply replace the inner text with the same text taken from the 2nd character (`substring(2)`)

---

This approach, as another user pointed out, works if you are **sure** that there is a bullet. If not I'd use a conditional in the code instead of `:contains(text)` selector, to have a general approach and make sure we strip only the character at the beginning (it's unlikely to have a bullet INSIDE the text, but `:contains()` would match also strings with this condition, which is wrong):

```
$(".dadosf").each(   
 function(i,e)
 {
     var t = $(e).text();
     if (t.substring(0,1) == "\u2022")
         $(e).text(t.substring(2));
 }
);
```

​

Comment: wasnt me. i would never downvote someone who is trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".dadosf:contains('.')").each(

 function()
 {
     $(this).text($(this).text().substring(2));
 }

);
```

Comment: The selector is not ok if the bullet is INSIDE the string.

Comment: That's not the point. Solutions should be reusable and account for exceptions and quirks: what if Google Maps, on which the OP has no control, returns a bullet INSIDE the string?. Although it might work in *this* case, you cannot draw a general conclusion from a snapshot.